# Having trouble installing Django 1.8 in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm in my project directory (a Django project) on the target device (Raspberry Pi) and want to install Django 1.8 in a virtual environment. I run the following commands:

```
sudo pip-3.2 install virtualenv
virtualenv-3.2 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip-3.2 install Django==1.8
```

But pip tries to install Django at `/usr/local/lib` and errors at:

```
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django': Permission denied
```

I thought that activating the virtual environment makes pip install things in the project `venv` dir. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip` instead of `pip-3.2`

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install Django==1.8
```

It seems `pip-3.2` is pointing to system pip. You can check by `which pip-3.2`

Comment: Ah, of course! After activating the virtual environment `pip` points to `venv/bin/pip` which is the pip that installs virtual environment packages, not `pip-3.2`. Thanks!